# Heroku Nodejs package fetch failed

Tags: node.js, bash, heroku

I was trying to deploy my node application in heroku and i am getting this error

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/jasonswett/heroku-buildpack-nodejs... done
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  4.4.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   3.9.6
remote:        
remote:        Downloading and installing node 4.4.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing npm 3.9.6 (replacing version 2.14.20)...
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Pruning any extraneous modules
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-regexp/-/escape-regexp-0.0.1.tgz
remote:        npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-regexp/-/escape-regexp-0.0.1.tgz
remote:        npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-regexp/-/escape-regexp-0.0.1.tgz
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_27e444d734bb50f3b3df0b13bc50d093/client/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_27e444d734bb50f3b3df0b13bc50d093/client/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_27e444d734bb50f3b3df0b13bc50d093/client/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v4.4.0
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! fetch failed with status code 502
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
remote:        npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_27e444d734bb50f3b3df0b13bc50d093/client/npm-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote:
```

I tried logging into heroku bash using `heroku run bash` command
and tried this

```
~ $ wget https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-regexp/-/escape-regexp-0.0.1.tgz
--2016-07-06 07:13:55--  https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-regexp/-/escape-regexp-0.0.1.tgz
Resolving registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)... 151.101.20.162
Connecting to registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)|151.101.20.162|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway
2016-07-06 07:13:55 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway.
```

**What does this 502 bad gateway mean, In my local if i try to get this package its working**

P.S In heroku all other urls i was able to access

```
~ $ wget https://registry.npmjs.org/
--2016-07-06 08:08:53--  https://registry.npmjs.org/
Resolving registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)... 151.101.20.162
Connecting to registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)|151.101.20.162|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 262 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[===========================================================================================================================================>] 262         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2016-07-06 08:08:54 (45.8 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [262/262]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open issue at NPM for this:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13284

Comment: yop, seems this is it. The fact `npm install` worked flawlessly on localhost (even without cache) put me on a wrong track.

Comment: Thank you, Now this issue has been fixed by npm :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also occurring on CodeShip. I think its a NPM issue

Comment: I don't think its an npm issue because i was able to fetch those package in my local